# How to ADB run command as background process AND THEN KILL IT?

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I've searched similar questions on the net, yet nothing is close to what I want, let's say my Windows script **( .bat)** is composed of many commands start with "adb shell" which would be executed sequentially:

*main.bat:*

```
  adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BUTTON_START

// here I want to trigger logcat background

  do something

// here I want to stop the background logcat then pull the logs to my desktop
```

I've tried many ways to do so like "nohup" or "&", however the script would be STUCK right after the logcat, hence the following commands wouldn't be triggered anymore. Also, I'm still wondering how can I fetch the background process id once I forked via "&"

Hope somebody could provide me the real script that is working :") Thanks again!

Comment: A simply but a bit "rude" possibility would be to call `taskkill /F /IM adb.exe /T` to end logcat. Instead of saving the logcat on device you should pipe it directly to a file on the PC.

Comment: In my opinion something like a  "wholesome script" does not exist, because a script is bad for recognizing the sate of the tests and the phone. You should better aim for a test program, not a script where you can perform multiple tasks simultaneously and have much more control on reading the different states and react accordingly.